# Addition of css class on widget file input has no effect

Tags: django

Try to add a `css class` into a `forms.ImageField`, has no effect.

model.py:-

```
class ProductImages(models.Model):
    ...    
    image_file_w200_png = models.ImageField(
        
        verbose_name = "Imagens",
        upload_to=upload_to_image_file_w200_png,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default='magickhat-profile.jpg'
    )
    ...
```

forms.py:-

```
class ProductImagesForm(ModelForm):
    image_file_w200_png = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'image_add_product'}))

    class Meta:
        model = ProductImages
        fields = ['image_file_w200_png']
```

That code has no effect, what is missing?

Edit:

admin.py

```
class UsersAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    site_header = 'Painel Administrativo'
    index_title = 'Painel Administrativo'
kadmin = UsersAdminSite(name='kadmin')
   
class AdminProductImages(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductImages
    extra = 1
    max_num = 10
    list_display = ('image_file_w200_png',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('image_file_w200_png',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ( 'image_file_w200_png'),
        }),
    )
kadmin.register(User, UserAdmin)
kadmin.register(Product, AdminProductModel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of your `image_file = forms.ImageField()` to be `image_file_w200_png`. What you are doing there currently is defining a new field rather than changing your existing field because the names are not the same.

You could also define it in a different way in your `class Meta:` section. You can add a dictionary called `widgets` and write it like this:

```
class Meta:
   model = ProductImages
   fields = ['image_file_w200_png']
   widgets = {'image_file_w200_png':forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'image_add_product'})}
```

Edit:
The original poster was trying to add a css class to their `admin.TabularInline` class in their `admin.py` file. This can be done by using the same form definition above in my answer and specifying in the `admin.TabularInline` class what form is used. Example:

```
class ModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = #Model Class Name Here
   form = #Form class Name Here
```

Comment: tks for atention Nathan, but is get no effect... Restart server, do what u suggest, but the result as the same...For now i try understand this note: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields , but no yeat

Comment: Is it not showing up on the html when you load the page? This definitely works because it is how it is done in the django docs and how I've done it on my own projects.

Comment: The result: `<input type="file" name="productimages_set-0-image_file_w200_png" accept="image/*" id="id_productimages_set-0-image_file_w200_png">`, idk if is relevant, is in admin `class AdminProductImages(admin.TabularInline):...`

Comment: Can you add your view that uses the image form to your post? As well as the section of your template that contains this form?

Comment: Is from `admin.urls` i dont, change a default, view or template...`/admin/<app>/<model>/add/`

Comment: This is for the admin page? Do you have an `admin.py` file in your app folder?

Comment: Yeap, let add admin.py to edit, a second pls, is done

Comment: The trick, is declare what `form` is used in `admin class`, so with your tip and `form = ProductImagesForm` in `class AdminProductImages(admin.TabularInline) work good. Tks dude, if u edit your answer, a can mark right ok...

Comment: I'm glad I could help somewhat, but the overall solution to your problem you figured out how to do. I have never used that `TabularInline` class before, so I couldn't help with that.

Comment: Yeah, i appreciate your help, and with your tip I managed to achieve the goal, and now you know more about this flow with admin concepts, and for new users if you put it in your question, is more complete anwser, and shoul be right.

Comment: Alright, I edited my answer. If what I added isn't sufficient in your opinion let me know.